# Rails, emails and html code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html-email

When my rails app sends an email to a gmail account with the body as html code dynamically generated, in the email the html code is displayed and the html is not rendered.

my html is dynamically generated something like this:

```
html = "<html><table> ...... </table></html>"
```

and the email displays all of that html code

Do i need to add any specific headers or anything?

Comment: Are you using a mailer view? If not, is there a reason for that?

Comment: yes I am using the mailer view. So I am creating an instance variable in my controller that contains the html.

Comment: If you're using a view you don't have to add HTML to a variable. It should just render an html.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Action Mailer Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#create-a-mailer-view). Sounds like you're only using the mailer part of Action Mailer. You should avoid hand crafting HTML into a variable like that, it's not the Rails-way.

I'd also suggest taking a look at Ryan Bate's screencast on [Sending HTML Email](http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
html.html_safe
```

to render the text of `html` as HTML type instead of plain text, or your tags will be html-escaped...